# Why does numpy array of booleans change to integers if concatenated with another array?

Tags: python, numpy, boolean, concatenation, numpy-ndarray

If I use `np.concatenate` to join this 1x5 array

```
array([True , False, False, True , True  ])
```

with this 1x5 array

```
array([4.753, 1.202, 2.296, 1.668, 3.35  ])
```

The booleans are changed to integers:

```
array([[1.   , 0.   , 0.   , 1.   , 1.   ],
       [4.753, 1.202, 2.296, 1.668, 3.35 ]])
```

Why? how can I concatenate them without affecting the booleans?

Ideally, the output can be a pandas DataFrame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```py
In [445]: import numpy as np
     ...: import pandas as pd

In [446]: data = {'Booleans': np.array([True, False, False, True, True]), 
     ...:          'Floats': np.array([4.753, 1.202, 2.296, 1.668, 3.35])}

In [447]: df = pd.DataFrame(data)

In [448]: df
Out[448]: 
   Booleans  Floats
0      True   4.753
1     False   1.202
2     False   2.296
3      True   1.668
4      True   3.350
```

You may find this link useful: [Different ways to create Pandas Dataframe](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/different-ways-to-create-pandas-dataframe/).

Answer (score 1):

One way is to set dtype of the individual arrays as `object` (you just need one of them to be `object` type to result in an `object` type array)

```
a = np.array([[True , False, False, True , True]], dtype=object)
b = np.array([[4.753, 1.202, 2.296, 1.668, 3.35]])

np.concatenate([a,b])
```

```
array([[True, False, False, True, True],
       [4.753, 1.202, 2.296, 1.668, 3.35]], dtype=object)
```

You can use `arr.astype()` to convert each array to `object` type after defining them as well.

```
a.astype(object)
#array([[True, False, False, True, True]], dtype=object)
```